# What's the power delivery of USB-C in Macbook 12-inch?

Tags: macbook-pro

What is the supplied power when a USB-C device is connected to these Macs, such as connecting an iPhone 7 Plus with a USB-C to Lightning cable.  I know the iPhone 7 Plus can take 1.8 to 2.0 A in tests I did.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics I know but to make it clear..

USB-C does not delivers (produces) power, it only carries it from one end to another.

The USB-C can carry 20 Volt and 5 Amp (100 watts).

The supplied power will depend on the device type (the consumer) and the source output (the supplier).

In case of iPhone 7, it needs 5 watt (5 Volt and 1 Amp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Buscar, I've edited my question.  I learnt what the power deliver is for 2016/17 Macbook Pros (up to 2 x 15w + 2 x 7.5w if it has 4 ports, if I remember rightly).  My doubt is what's the power delivery in the 12-inch Macbooks.